# How to set an image as the background view for a uiTableView in XCode 4.3.2

Tags: ios5, uiimage, uitableview, xcode4.3

XCode Version: 4.3.2
iOS 5.0

I am trying to set the background image for my TableViewController. I have a table already in the controller, just not sure how and where (which method to write the code in) to set the background image for this. Once I set it does anyone also know how to put the table at the bottom of the screen? If someone can outline the steps, i would be grateful.

Really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it inside the viewDidLoad method. For example so:

```
UIImageView *bgView = [UIImageView ....];
self.tableView.backgroundView = bgView;
[bgView release];
```

Comment: I have to release this in X Code 4.3.2?

Comment: thanks for the help it works! By any chance do you know how to move the table to the bottom of the screen? It is currently at the top .

Comment: @Masterminder what do you mean with the "bottom of the screen"? a UITableView fills normally the whole parent view. But i think, it should be an another question.

Please accept my answer if it was helpful. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info! Thanks

Comment: When I Created the table, XCode Automatically places it at the top part of the screen, I want it to be shifted downwards so I can see the image in the background. Hope that is clear!

Comment: @Masterminder if you want, that your table cells come after the image, i would place the image not in the background of the whole table, but as table section or table header content (before the cells). If i understood what you want.